# Bug in Gmail app on Iphone

Tags: html, css

I am kinda new to campaign monitor and responisve email templates. I am building a responsive template that works in all email clients but I have an issue with the email on gmail in iphone. Height:auto !important does not seem to work and the image gets stretched.

Here's my code. All the styles are made inline using campaign monitor inliner tool.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=0, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title></title>

    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse !important;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
    <style type="text/css">
        @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
            .full-width-image img {
                height: auto !important;
                max-width: 600px !important;
                width: 100% !important;
            }
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body yahoo="fix" style="margin-top:0 !important;margin-bottom:0 !important;margin-right:0 !important;margin-left:0 !important;padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;background-color:#ffffff;">
    <center class="wrapper" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;">
        <div class="webkit" style="max-width:600px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
            <tr>
            <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
            <![endif]-->
            <table class="outer" align="center" style="border-spacing:0; font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;Margin:0 auto;max-width:600px; width:95%;">

                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center">
                                    <a href="https://www.enviodinero.ca/enviodinero/"><img editable="true" src="images/envio_com.jpg" width="300" style="max-width:300px; width:100%;" /></a>
                                </td>

                            </tr>
                            <tr><td align="center" style="color:#7b808f;"><singleline label='Basic Links'>Hurricane help | </singleline><webversion style="color:#7b808f;text-decoration:underline" target="_blank">Online Version</webversion></td></tr>
                        </table>

                    </td>
                </tr>
                <repeater>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <img editable="true" src="images/600x300.jpg" width="600" height="600" alt="" style="border-width:0; max-width:600px; width:100%; height:auto; margin-bottom:5px;" />
                        </td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </repeater>
                <repeater>
                    <tr>

                        <td class="three-column" style="padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                <tr>
                <td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
                </tr>
                </table>
                <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </repeater>

                <tr>
                    <td class="full-width-image" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <img editable="true" src="images/600x300.jpg" width="600" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:600px;height:auto !important;margin-bottom:5px;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" style="padding-top:5px;padding-bottom:5px;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                        <img editable="true" src="images/140x70.jpg" width="130" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:130px; height:auto !important;" />
                    </td>

                </tr>

                <repeater>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="full-width-image" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                            <img editable="true" src="images/600x300.jpg" width="600" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:600px;height:auto !important;margin-bottom:5px;" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </repeater>
                <repeater>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="three-column" style="padding-right:0;padding-left:0;text-align:center;font-size:0;padding-top:10px;padding-bottom:10px;">
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;" >
                            <tr>
                            <td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                            <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                            <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            </td><td width="200" valign="top" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;" >
                            <![endif]-->
                            <div class="column" style="width:100%;display:inline-block;vertical-align:top;max-width:190px;">
                                <table width="100%" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="inner" style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                            <table class="contents" style="border-spacing:0;font-family:sans-serif;color:#333333;font-size:14px;text-align:center;">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="padding-top:0;padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;">
                                                        <img editable="true" src="images/200x200.jpg" width="180" alt="" style="border-width:0;width:100%;max-width:180px;height:auto !important;" />
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td class="text" style="padding-bottom:0;padding-right:0;padding-left:0;padding-top:10px;">
                                                        <multiline label='Service Intro'>Scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</multiline>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                            </td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                            <![endif]-->
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </repeater>


            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The bug is in the last image. The width works fine but the height is stretched in iphone gmail app

Comment: Gmail does not take into account everything that is written in the head section

Comment: Yep thats y i made the styles inline (height:auto !important)but that does not work either

Comment: Would be useful to have the code below the image, all of the closing tags are missing and can make it difficult to see the structure of what you're going for. As per the above comment, Gmail was updated last month and does now support css embedded in the <head> section

Comment: yep but m working on old gmail clients and theres just one more row below what i posted. Everything else works fine except this image

Comment: I posted the entire code... I really need help to track this bug..

Comment: If it's an old gmail that's displaying the desktop version of the build then the issue is you have height=600 when the image has a height of 300. I'm not overly familiar with Campaign Monitor specific tags, so can't help much

Comment: the image has height of 600 px . its just the name bcz i had 300 height before